# R studio Javascript Alert R encountered a fatal error

Tags: r, rstudio

### Issue description

When opening R studio, after about 10 seconds, I get a popup alert:

```
Javascript Alert-http://127.0.0.1:40055/
R encountered a fatal error.
The session was terminated.
```

If I click the OK button on the alert I get another alert:

```
Javascript Alert-http://127.0.0.1:40055/
null
```

After clicking OK again, I get the error in the console:

```
Error: Unable to establish connection with R session
```

I cannot run anything (it just has the flashing cursor permanently). I cannot click any options (e.g. if I click Tools -> Global options, then the drop down closes without doing anything).

### What I have tried

- Restarting my computer.
- Reinstalling R and R studio.
- Removing the project and history files associated with the project.
- Uninstalling all my packages (I presume unnecessary but I was getting desperate).
- Moving the config file `mv ~/.config/RStudio ~/backup-RStudio` (from https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State). I also tried moving .rstudio-desktop, but that didn't exist.

### Possibly useful information

The error first started after I tried to compile and run C code in R. I think I made an infinite loop, either way it crashed R and I `xkill`ed it. R still runs fine from the terminal.

### Versions

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)

rstudio version 1.4.1103

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: When you reinstalled R, did you reinstall to the latest version (4.1.0), or 3.6.3?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error message:

> Javascript Alert: R encountered a fatal error. The session was
> terminated.

For me this error occurred after changing from the 64-bit to 32-bit versions of R. I tried:

- restarting my machine
- uninstalling/reinstalling Rstudio
- installing an older version of Rstudio which has been more stable in the past

None of these worked for me, but when I deleted my ".Rhistory" file in my home directory the error message disappeared and I'm now able to run my scripts again.

Additional info:
I'm using Windows 10, Rstudio Desktop 1.4.1717 and R4.1.0 (32 and 64 bit versions)

Update: Rstudio showed the same error message again, but [resetting the RStudio Desktop's state](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State) helped.